# SQL - Retrieving results from 3 tables and ordering them by date

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Let's say I have these three tables:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║   ║ Name       ║ Date                ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Bob        ║ 2018-07-30 14:20:03 ║
║ 2 ║ Dylan      ║ 2018-07-29 14:20:03 ║
║ 3 ║ Frank      ║ 2018-07-17 14:20:03 ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════════════╝

╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║   ║ Name       ║ Date                ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Bernard    ║ 2018-07-31 14:20:03 ║
║ 2 ║ Max        ║ 2018-07-28 14:20:03 ║
║ 3 ║ Dan        ║ 2018-07-16 14:20:03 ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════════════╝

╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║   ║ Name       ║ Date                ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Maria      ║ 2018-07-12 14:18:03 ║
║ 2 ║ Sofia      ║ 2018-07-30 14:23:03 ║
║ 3 ║ Lila       ║ 2018-07-25 14:22:03 ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

I would like to know how to select the first 3 elements, ordered by date (closest date from now first) so that in the end, the result of my query looks like this:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║   ║ Name       ║ Date                ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Bernard    ║ 2018-07-31 14:20:03 ║
║ 2 ║ Sofia      ║ 2018-07-30 14:23:03 ║
║ 3 ║ Bob        ║ 2018-07-30 14:20:03 ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Cheers!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite...they're not the same thing.

Comment: I'm using both. SQLite to test things out locally, MySQL on the server when stuff's ready.

Comment: Be aware that this kind of problem can be symptomatic of a poorly designed schema.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table3
) tmp
ORDER BY DATE DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Neither MySQL or SQLite support the `TOP` keyword; they use `LIMIT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need `union all` with `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from ( select *, row_number() over (partition by tablename order by date desc) seq
       from ( (select name, date, 'table1' as tablename
               from table1 t1
              ) union all
              (select name, date, 'table2'
               from table2 t2
              ) union all
              (select name, date, 'table3'
               from table3 t3
              )
           ) t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: The inclusion of the tablename column dispenses with the need for the ALL keyword.